# The + operator in regular expressions

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata

I am a bit confused about the notation that is used in the book I am reading.

Let's say I have such a regular expression

```
(a + b)*(aa + bb)(a + b)*
```

So starting from the first one, I will pick either `a` or `b` or none then I have to add `aa` or `bb` then again I will pick either `a` or `b` or none.

so some of the words below belong to this regular expression:
aaa
aaab
bba

but for example `abaa` is not accepted.

However, the author gives a finite automata like that:

[image]

The author says the regular expression belong to this finite automata is

```
(a + b)*(aa + bb)(a + b)*
```

Same like above. But based on the graph, `abaa` can be achieved. However, I cannot produce `abaa` with the regular expression above. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Your diagram has tiny writing that I cannot read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes in interpreting the Kleene star.  $(a+b)^\star$ means an arbitrary number of $(a+b)$'s.  Hence, this is an arbitrary string, of length $0$ or longer, containing either $a$'s or $b$'s in any order.

To get $abaa$, interpret the expression first as $(a+b)(a+b)(aa+bb)$, where we take the first $(a+b)^\star$  twice and the second $(a+b)^\star$  zero times.  Then, interpret this as $abaa$.

Comment: wow okay. I was applying * operator to the letters inside of the parantheses. thanks!!